# Odd jQuery IE problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to implement this function which works everywhere except every IE version (go figure)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $('#twitterUserTimeline').liveTwitter('#regional from:el_carabobeno', {refresh: false, mode: 'search', showAuthor: false}, function(container, newCount){
           $(".tweet:not(:first)").addClass('hidden'); // hide all twets but the first one
         });

         $("#twitterUserTimeline").hover(function () { // on hover
            $(".tweet:not(:first)").removeClass('hidden'); // reveals them
          }, function () { // on out
            $(".tweet:not(:first)").addClass('hidden'); // hide them again
          }
        );
     });
</script>
```

IE doesn't seem to like those selectors, because if I removed them everything works.

Comment: Which selectors are giving an issue, and which version of jQuery?

Comment: all of them, If I remove everything that "selects" those tweet classes the tweets are loaded, if I leave the code as it is, everything works on every browser but IE, (can't see the error because I am using screenshots)

Version is 1.4.2, actually you can see it work/and not work here http://s2.el-carabobeno.com/secciones/regional

Comment: Does it change anything if you bind that to document.ready? Maybe IE needs the element to exist when you initialise that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get IE to fall into line you need to write out the full selector again in the not clause:

```
$(".tweet:not(.tweet:first)").addClass('hidden');
```

[In action](http://jsfiddle.net/Pe7wv/).